# Compose biggest-sum row solution from two dimensional array algorithm optimalization

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, combinations

Suppose we have a two dimensional array (N rows, M columns), in which each column has at least one non-empty cell with integer value:

[image: Data]

We can easily compose a new single row, in which each cell contains the biggest value taken from according column in data array.

**The solution (length M) cannot have empty values.**

In this case, the solution would be:

[image: Solution]

There is a single factor: biggest value for each column.

We want to add another factor: lowest amount of rows from which the solution is being composed from (**more important** than sum value).

The simplest algorithm for this would be as following:

i = 1

```
while (i <= M)
{
    candidates = generateCorrectSolutionsFromAllNLengthRowCombinations(i)

    if ( ! empty(candidates))
    {
        return biggestSumElement(candidates)
    }

    i++
}
```

This algorithm returns correct solution, but has very high computional complexity which is problematic for bigger matrices.

Is there a way to do it faster? Was this problem (or similar one) analyzed anywhere?

Regards,

Patryk

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding values in unordered array, you never know, if the value you are looking for is in the last visited field of that array, therefore the complexity for array of length N is O(N) and cannot be smaller.

The only way how to make searching faster is to have array ordered in some way, or to know some pattern and based on that skip some part of array, because we are sure, the solution is not there.